# Detecting and reducing duplicate binary files stored in SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, md5

In our application, we let the user generate and send a wide variety of documents through it. Some of these will always be unique but a large percentage of them will be static. We store the files in a SQL 2008 DB using a FileStream for the actual data. I am looking for a way to detect when a file has already been stored so I don't store a duplicate.

I am thinking of generating a hash, using MD5 and using that hash as a key into the SQL database. What I am afraid of is the possibility of a collision occurring.

Some question I have are:

1: What is the likelyhood of getting a collision on the hash? Should I treat the unique key to be a combination of FileName, Size of File plus Hash?

2: What would you store the resulting hash as in the database? Should we store it as a binary field as?

Comment: Store a hash and, in the event of a match, verify the contents of the files.  You only need to check on inserts and updates, and matches should be quite infrequent.  (Check Wikipedia or other resources for the odds of a collision for various hash algorithms.)  Just don't make the hash column `unique`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of very common interview questions - so should have plenty of long discussions :).

1. [birthday paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) - so relatively high. But some data that can be obtained in constant time (like size, first/last X bytes) can make "hash" longer and hence probability of collision more acceptable. I'd use something producing longer hash (Sha256?) to start with.
2. I'd use Base64 string of Sha256 hash + whatever other bits are useful (or any other indexable field, which I believe binary are not).

Side note I would not use File Name as part of "hash" as it is not part of binary data itself and can change independently.

Comment: Thanks I was already leaning towards Base64, and looking at the chance of Collision SHA256 has a significantly less chance that makes more sense....I have the resources to do the longer calculation